# gifsicle binary not found while starting reactjs app

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering, react-ssr, gifsicle

We use gifsicle version 5.1.0 in package.json, but the application start throws the following error. It is expecting a binary gifsicle under node_modules/gifsicle/vendor folder but trying to start the application with "yarn dev" is not working. Any pointers would be helpful

```
webpack:///./node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/ajax-loader.gif?:1
throw new Error("Module build failed (from ./node_modules/image-webpack-loader/index.js):\nError: spawn /home/user/webapp/node_modules/gifsicle/vendor/gif
sicle ENOENT\n    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:269:19)\n    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:465:16)\n    at processTicksAndRejections (inte
rnal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)");
```

The error seems to be as follows

```
Output:
⚠ Response code 404 (Not Found)
  ⚠ gifsicle pre-build test failed
  ℹ compiling from source
  ✖ Error: Command failed: /bin/sh -c ./configure --disable-gifview --disable-gifdiff --prefix="/home/user/webapp/node_modules/gifsicle/vendor" --bindir="
/home/user/webapp/node_modules/gifsicle/vendor"
    config.status: error: in `/tmp/7314af85-eb99-48d5-963f-47a8d2e141a1':
    config.status: error: Something went wrong bootstrapping makefile fragments
        for automatic dependency tracking.  Try re-running configure with the
        '--disable-dependency-tracking' option to at least be able to build
        the package (albeit without support for automatic dependency tracking).
    See `config.log' for more details

config.log contains the following

gcc version 9.3.0 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04)
configure:3384: $? = 0
configure:3373: gcc -V >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:3384: $? = 1
configure:3373: gcc -qversion >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-qversion'; did you mean '--version'?
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:3384: $? = 1
configure:3404: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:3426: gcc    conftest.c  >&5
configure:3430: $? = 0
configure:3478: result: yes
configure:3481: checking for C compiler default output file name
configure:3483: result: a.out

        Environment:
        nvm use 14.15.1
        Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
```

Comment: Is `/home/user/webapp/node_modules/gifsicle/vendor/gif` there or not? Are there any errors when you run `yarn install`?

Comment: after vendor its source/gifsicle-1.92.tar.gz and no errors. on yarn install

Comment: I have added more errors in the description

Comment: Can you downgrade the version of Gifsicle you're using? Looks like there is a standing issue w/ the binary on Linux that hasn't been resolved since last March: https://github.com/imagemin/gifsicle-bin/issues/113

Comment: 4.0.1 migration helps

Answer (score 1):

Migrating to 4.0.1 resolved the problem